# Eclipse throwing error on invalid modifiers, rename in file

Tags: java, eclipse, oop, variables, variable-declaration

I'm a beginner in Java and I was typing this block of code in Eclipse and it is throwing errors like this. I haven't even started anything yet, but there's error with my variable name? I know Eclipse is very particular about duplicate variable names in maybe the same package or something. Is that maybe where the problem is?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to either declare those variables outside the `main` method (if you want them to have class scope), or remove the `private` keyword if you want them to have method scope, i.e. just in your main method.

So either this:

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    // other variables...
    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        // other code...
    }
}
```

Or like this:

```
public class Person {
    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        String name;
        // other variables and code...
    }
}
```

Comment: By the way, eclipse's suggestion to "remove invalid modifiers" (as shown in your screenshot) will do the second of my two examples for you automagically. Oh, and I would _really_ recommend choosing a different (fixed-width) font... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can not use the access modifier `private` inside any method. Remove the access modifier `private` before the variable name.

Or you can declare these variable in class level (that is as instance variables) - outside of any methods. Since the `name` is a property/attribute of a `Person`, according to `OOP` it is better to keep the name as field of the `Person` class like this -

```
public class Person{

   private String name;
   //Other property of Person

   public String getName(){
      return name;
   }

   public String setName(String name){
      this.name = name;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args){


   }

}
```

Use public getter and setter method to access these private variable from outside of the `Person` class.

Answer (score 1):

Either do this:

```
public class Person {
    private String name; // Declared as an attribute of Person class

    public static void main(String [] args) { ...}
}
```

Or this:

```
public class Person {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        String name; // No private
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the access modifier private in both the variables.Your problem

will be solved.You cannot declare private variables inside methods.